# inline event handlers not working after cloning in react.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Hello everybody i am observing an issue when trying to clone a react component(cloning the parent div of react component) which makes the inline event handler somehow disabled/removed and no events can be fired from the cloned component yet the original works fine.As far as i have searched the javascript cloneNode method should work for inline event handlers and it does too for plain html and javascript but somehow i cant seem to get it to work in react.js

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Football extends React.Component {
  shoot() {
    alert("Great Shot!");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.shoot}>Take the shot!</button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Football />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="root"></div>
     <button "onclick=CloneIt()">CloneIt</button>
<script>
function CloneIt(){
var elem=document.getElementById("mainComp").cloneNode(true);
document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React doesn't actually create an inline event, even if you write the event inline.

JSX is not actual html, it's just syntactic sugar that gets converted to `React.createElement` by babel for react.

So your inline onClick event actually becomes `props.onClick`, a property of props object passed as second parameter to React.createElement.

Internally react attaches the event listener using `addEventListener`.

When you clone a React element and append it to DOM, the newly appended element wont have any links to the react component. So, if you want the onClick event to work as it worked with the original DOM, you need to hydrate the element with react component.

```
var elem = document.getElementById("root").cloneNode(true);
document.body.appendChild(elem);
ReactDOM.hydrate(<Football />, elem);
```

Comment: Wow man @AvcS you really nailed it dude.btw if i change id from root to the one of actual component div's then it gives error server html expecetd matching div div

Comment: Yes when you are hydrating a DOM element with React component, the structure should match with the DOM generated by component. And its ideal to use classes instead of id's when dealing with clones.